# Как понять куда передать запрос

Tags: python, html, form

есть форма на сайте, не имеющая никакого action, а имеющая какую-то data-phx-id=<Случайные символы>, то есть выглядит следующим образом:

```
<form method="post" id="form-compact" phx-change="validate" phx-hook="SpeechRecognizer" phx-submit="submit" data-phx-id="phx-F7lcXMKdL27Nkg5k-8"> ... </form>
```

Вот как такой форме (со всеми полями с данными) передать post-запрос через библиотеку requests на python? По той же ссылке через post выдает ошибку 404, то есть такого роута не существует, странице по-моему даже обновляться не нужно

Comment: Смотрите мониторинг сети в браузерных девтулзах и не смотрите html-код потому что в этом нет смысла

Comment: Судя по тому, что выдаёт гугль, это `JS` движок `Phoenix LiveView`. Как он там внутри себя `HTML` теги интерпретирует - поди догадайся. Нужно мониторить сетевые запросы, согласен с предыдущим оратором.